# Laravel belongsTo() column naming issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I can't figure out how to make aliases for my table column names such that I can use Laravel's Eloquent `belongsTo()` functionality.

I have a `groups` table and and an `activities` table. The `activities` table references the `groups` table by `organization_id` rather than `groups_id`.

How do I write belongsTo in my Activity model as the following doesn't work.

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Group', 'organization_id');
}
```

What I'd like to write is:

```
App\Activity->group
```

Comment: What error or issue are you getting by _the following doesn't work_.

Comment: hold on @AhmadBaktashHayeri, will produce it for you...

Comment: according to documentation this is the syntax `$this->belongsTo('App\User', 'local_key', 'parent_key');` i think organization id would be the third parameter not the second

Comment: Actually my code just ran successfully. I migrated my DB for something else so that must have fixed everything. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Maybe in misreading but shouldn't this be a 'hasOne'  relationship?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the code you have pasted laravel will think that the organization id is the column in your activities table which your are using as foreign key what you should do is :

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Group', 'organization_id', 'id');
}
```

in the above code you will get all results where activies.id = groups.organization_id;

**UPDATE by Tim Peterson**

My original code works. I migrated my DB for something else so that must have fixed everything.